# Problem Laravel Can't send a form to my mail

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.4

> Finally !!! I found the problem and I'm ashamed , I just modified the
>   bad .env.... As you can see I modified the .env.example and not the
>   .env !!!! I really appreciate your support . It was just a stupide
>   mistake ^^

+++

I try so hard to resolve this problem . I need to send a contact form to my mailbox with Laravel . Maybe you prefer my repository git.

There is the error [image : error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZKc2c.png)

Here is the mail.php

```
<?php return [

'driver' => env('MAIL_DRIVER', 'smtp'),

'host' => env('MAIL_HOST', 'smtp.gmail.com'),

'port' => env('MAIL_PORT', 587),

'from' => ['address' => 'a@a.com',

'name' => 'Test'],

'encryption' => env('MAIL_ENCRYPTION', 'tls'),

'username' => env('MAIL_USERNAME'),

'password' => env('MAIL_PASSWORD'),

'sendmail' => '/usr/sbin/sendmail -bs',

'markdown' => [
    'theme' => 'default',

    'paths' => [
        resource_path('views/vendor/mail'),
    ],
],    
];
```

My web.php

```
<?php
Route::get('contact', 'ContactController@getForm');
Route::post('contact', 'ContactController@postForm');
```

ContactRequest.php

```
<?php
namespace App\Http\Requests;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Http\FormRequest;
class ContactRequest extends FormRequest
{
/**
 * Determine if the user is authorized to make this request.
 *
 * @return bool
 */
public function authorize()
{
    return true;
}

/**
 * Get the validation rules that apply to the request.
 *
 * @return array
 */
public function rules()
{
    return [
        'nom' => 'required|min:5|max:20|alpha',
        'email' => 'required|email',
        'texte' => 'required|max:250'
    ];
}
}
```

ContactController.php

```
<?php
 namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use Mail;
use App\Http\Requests\ContactRequest;
class ContactController extends Controller {


public function getForm()
{
    return view('contact');
}

public function postForm(ContactRequest $request)
{
    Mail::send('email_contact', $request->all(), function($message)
    {
        $message->to('a@a.com')->subject('Contact');
    });

    return view('confirm');
}
}
```

.env.example
[Image : code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/icAa7.png)

UserController.php

```
<?php
namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Requests;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
class UsersController extends Controller      
{
public function getInfos()

{
    return view('infos');
}

public function postInfos(Request $request)
{
    return 'Le nom est ' . $request->input('nom') ." ".$request->input('prenom');

}
}
```

I don't know where is the problem, probably in the function _assertResponseCode but I don't know what I can write...

Edited ::

[Second picture of my security account](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2Ylcq.png)

[New Picture of my security account](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d27sJ.png)

Comment: You are using gmail as per your SMTP Server ? Make sure about username and password correct in this case

Comment: Can you try with `ssl` instead of `tls`

Comment: go here and activate the less secure apps in the mail  box you wanna  send it with https://myaccount.google.com/lesssecureapps?pli=1

Comment: Sorry didn't' saw you'r post . So I replace tls for ssl but nothing change, I use the great password and mail_username (my email) 
If I understand you  I need to have less security but I already test with security and without but nothing . Or are u saying I need to use the "App password" ? for my gmail  box ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error from your image says that authentication is required so you need to enable your two steps verification from your gmail account.

https://myaccount.google.com/security

Also you can generate key from the above link and then set your `MAIL_PASSWORD` instead your real password.

Comment: The same error I already do these steps for normal php contact form

Comment: Are you sure you enabled the authentication! Plus make sure your email and password is correct.

Comment: The error image says that 2 step verification is disabled can you try enabling it

Comment: Ohh yes my bad , I change now and I put  2-step Verification but that doesn't work . The password and email are good . I put a screen with the 2-step . Maybe I forgot something else but what?

Answer (score 0):

Have you enabled SMTP in your Gmail settings?

Go to the "Settings", e.g. click on the "Gears" icon and select "Settings".
Click on "Forwarding and POP/IMAP".
Enable "IMAP Access" and/or "POP Download"